# How to create MongoDB indexes automatically with Lift Framework?

Tags: mongodb, orm, record, lift

I am using Lift Framework with Record as ORM and Mongo as database. Then I change used indexes, I go to remote mongo console, and ensure indexes by hand.

I want to automate it so that Lift will ensure indexes at every start of server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anwser was found [here](https://github.com/eltimn/lift-mongo.g8/blob/master/src/main/g8/src/main/scala/%24package%24/model/User.scala#L79):

1. То do some action on app loading, simply put it in the class definition.
2. [MongoMeta](http://liftweb.net/api/25/api/net/liftweb/mongodb/MongoMeta.html) has ensureIndex function which creates index just like MongoDB native ensureIndex does.